APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB: does it exist outside wikipedia? What is the correct formulation?
In this Wikipedia page there is the description of the problem APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB, complete for BQP:

Given a description of a quantum circuit $C$ acting on $n$ qubits with $m$ gates, where $m$ is a polynomial in $n$ and each gate acts on one or two qubits, and two numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta \in [0,1]$, $\alpha > \beta$,
distinguish between the following two cases:


measuring the first qubit of the state $C\left|0\right>^{\otimes n}$ yields $\left|1\right>$
with probability $\ge \alpha$


measuring the first qubit of the state $C\left|0\right>^{\otimes n}$ yields $\left|1\right>$
with probability $\le \beta$


Here, there is a promise on the inputs as the problem does not specify the behavior if an instance is not covered by these two cases.

This problem is often mentioned, e.g. in lecture slides, oral presentation, websites, but I do not see anything on it in papers. I would like to have:

A literature reference where the problem is defined and the BQP-completeness is proved. The reference should be a peer-reviewed paper, a textbook, or, at least, a real paper on arxiv.

If such a reference is not available, an answer should provide a rigorous definition and a sketch of the proof.


Moreover, in the definition above, there is clearly something wrong: the request that $m$ is polynomial in $n$. Such a condition is perfectly valid in a class definition, but it is meaningless in this context. I tried to raise the attention on this problem, but, after reading the comments, I see that it is difficult to discuss the topic, because there is no proof available of the BQP-completeness. Everybody speaks of a different thing. Someone says that the proof is trivial, but I do not even understand which definitions they have in mind (not even of BQP!). Unless we have at least a sketch of the proof, it is hard to discuss. And, at the moment, it seems that no proof is published.

It's always about families. And the problem is essentially the definition of BQP (or at least one of the standard definitions) - which is the definition you have in mind in the last part of your question?

I am looking for a literature reference where there is the definition of APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB and the proof that it is BQP-complete. About the family, I still do not clearly understand how a rigorous definition should be. I am surprised of this bound, because we do not have it in other, analogous, cases, like in SAT; there, the size of the circuit simply counts in the input length.

Classical circuits also need to have a number of gates or runtime which scales polynomially with the input size or the number of bits.

Of course, the scaling is important. Do you have a literature reference for a problem based on circuits where there is this bound? As an example, in SAT there is no limitation. In the definitions of CIRCUIT-SAT that I have seen, this bound does not appear; do you have a literature reference where there is the bound?

On a second thought, you might have a point here: Since the input is the circuit, the scaling just has to be efficient in the size of the circuit description. So I agree no scaling or uniformity is needed. Of course, if $n\sim\log(m)$, this will not be BQP-complete.

@NorbertSchuch so then wouldn't the problem have required to be polynomial in $n\times m$? Perhaps describing it as dependent on the number of qubits is the wrong variable, and doesn't represent "the size of the circuit description".

@Mark The input size is certainly what is required to describe the input, i.e. the circuit -- which is basically $m$ since $n$ cannot be larger than $O(m)$. (More precisely, each $k$-qubit gate requires $O((\log n)^k)$ bits.)

I think you might have a better chance with a textbook than a paper.

I edited the question adding the possibility that the reference is a textbook. Do you have one to suggest? I think that the proof is not as simple as someone thinks: we cannot simply claim that the computer executes the quantum circuit in input, rather we have to resort to universal quantum computation. That's why I would like to see the proof.

Why cannot we claim that? And for which part of the proof: containment or hardness? Of course, it depends what your definition of BQP is.

For the containment. The definition of BQP states that the polynomially generated quantum circuits B_n only depend on the size n of the input. You cannot take the input Q and use it as B. You must have a B which performs universal computation, taking Q as input! I would like to see the proof to check how this is done. I think it is not trivial.

Just use controlled gates, or delegate this to a classical control circuit. Once more, it will depend on how you specify the circuit, from which gateset, etc., as well as how you define BQP.

I take the definition of BQP in wikipedia, above the definition of APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB. Yes, we can use the controlled gates. But then the input is the description of the circuit itself. with size m. There is nothing wrong is then the circuit with controlled gates has length m, If you write down a proof, whatever is the definition of BQP you like, you see that the condition n<p(m) does not make any sense.

I agree that there is no need for the condition on the scaling of m. I thought this was settled. The input size is m, rather than n.

Well, yes, it is settled between us! My problem is that I was using these things in a paper of mine and a reviewer complained about the lack of the condition m<p(n). If no reference really exists, would you be interested in co-authoring a very short paper (at least in arxiv) with a clear definition and proof of completeness? I do not dare to make it alone.

Does one need a promise on how the gap $\alpha-\beta$ behaves as a function of $n$?

@Doriano Note that while the condition is not needed, you can impose such a condition and the problem is still (promise-)BQP-complete. (Indeed, if $n$ is much smaller than poly(m), say n = log(m), this is not BQP-hard any more, as it can be simulated in LOGSPACE, so the relevant regime does indeed require a polynomial relation between m and n.

@Norbert : I think I get your point. But I am not sure that it is exactly what we need in the definition.  Do you claim that there is a p(n) such that the definition of APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB works limiting m<=p(n)? The reason why I am reluctant to accept this idea is that the uniformly generated quantum circuits appearing in the class BQP can have whatever p(n), we cannot fix this p(n) for all of them.

What I don't understand: Instead of using this problem in a paper, why don't you connect whatever problem you have directly to BQP? APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB is basically just the BQP-definition rewritten, so reducing things directly from/to BQP should work just as well (or not well).

Yes, it works and it is what I will do. However, there are some details of the proof that are not straightforward, at least for me. So, I wonder why we cannot have a literature reference for this APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB.
